# How can I change number to negative number in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, numbers

The absolutes variable represents a number.
The sign attempts to convert "-" into a number "++" when "negative number" is "positive number".
We're going to solve the task of adding all the variables that we changed.

a[i] = absolutes[i].unaryMinus()

In this sentence,
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1

An error appears.

Can I know which part is wrong?

```
    val absolutes = intArrayOf(4,7,12)
    val sign = arrayOf(true,false,true)

    val a = intArrayOf(0)

    for (i in absolutes.indices){

        if (!sign[i]) {
            a[i] = absolutes[i].unaryMinus()
        }
    }

    val result = a.sum()

    Log.d(logTag, "onCreate is called result = $result")
```

Comment: Note that you could avoid the issue entirely by simply using built-in collection operations, such as `absolutes.zip(sign).sumOf { (absValue, isPositive) -> if (isPositive) absValue else -absValue }`, or using `foldIndexed` as in one of the answers. Not having to think about the specifics is a great benefit of the Kotlin stdlib

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`intArrayOf` from the Kotlin standard library ["Returns an array containing the specified Int numbers"](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/int-array-of.html).

Thus, your value of `a` is an `IntArray` of `size` 1.
You cannot assign values to indices above the `lastIndex`, which in this case is 0.

I assume you aimed to create an `IntArray` of the same size as your input, filled with zeroes by default.

```kotlin
val a = IntArray(absolutes.size)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have created an array `a` with 1 element so when referencing `a[1]` you are hitting the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.
Either declare the array as val a = intArrayOf(0, 0, 0) or reduce the initial array.

```
val absolutes = intArrayOf(4, 7, 12)
val sign = arrayOf(true, false, true)

absolutes.foldIndexed(0) { index, acc, element ->
    return@foldIndexed if (sign[index]) {
        acc + element
    } else {
        acc - element
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you have the signs inverted in the fold's body.

Comment: Could be, I am not sure if the question was to negate if it's `true` or `false`

Comment: OP's doing `if (!sign[i]) { ...unaryMinus() }` that's why I believe the sign should be understood this way